# nginx -v command not found

Tags: nginx

I successfully installed nginx  ~ but when I use nginx -v command, it show : nginx: command not found

what the problem?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: The problem is that your system can't find nginx. It is indeed very important for us to know how it was installed. If, for example, you followed the instructions on the site to compile it manually, which I strongly discourage, it might not have gotten installed in the right place or ever got copied from the build directory.

Comment: @MetaNova When you want to install the RTMP module, it is required to compile Nginx manually, causing to be installed in `/usr/local/nginx` and you find yourself in much trouble. Then how to install the rtmp module without having to compile it manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

run echo $PATH
Does it contain /usr/local/sbin?

If not try `PATH=/usr/sbin/:$PATH`

Also, check that nginx is installed in /usr/local/sbin, by going into this directory.

Comment: @ekincrue How did you finally solve it? Can you add the details?

Answer (score 4):

First, find out where nginx is installed by showing all running processes for `nginx`:

```
pgrep nginx | xargs ps -f -p
```

Look for the nginx master process in the list, it should show the location where the `nginx` process is e.g `/usr/sbin/nginx`

> (for more info about what the `pgrep ...` is doing, see
>   https://serverfault.com/questions/77162/how-to-get-pgrep-to-display-full-process-info/210823#210823)

Now, check if the containing folder (for example `/usr/sbin/`) is in your path:

```
echo $PATH
```

If it's not there, you need to add it. To add it to the path and persist the change between your linux terminal sessions, edit the profile for the user that you want to be able to persistently access the `nginx` command. First, ensure you're logged in as the user, then edit the `.profile` file that's in the user's home directory. If you have `nano`, then you can do this with:

```
sudo nano ~/.profile
```

Add the following at the end of the `.profile` file (use the correct folder - I'm using `/usr/sbin/ as an example):

```
export PATH=/usr/sbin/:$PATH
```

This *prepends* `/usr/sbin/` to the user's path whilst retaining the existing path (`$PATH` is a variable that points to everything else that's already in the path)

Now you need to source (effectively 'refresh') your profile file so that the change takes effect:

```
. ~/.profile
```

Now try `nginx -v`

Here's [a good resource about editing your path](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/path-variable). I got a lot of my answer from here.